# I uninstalled lxde using all methods but still lubuntu screen displays while logging in

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, gui, lxde

[image]

I have uninstalled lxde using terminal and it is not visible in my laptop but still its screen is displayed while logging in, and in the list of desktop environments options it is available

Comment: What was your original install (Lubuntu or Ubuntu)?  What other desktop environments have you installed?  What command did you use to uninstall?

Comment: My original install was Ubuntu. I uninstalled lxde using sudo apt-get autoremove lxde. then sudo apt-get autoremove lubuntu-desktop. and also used purge command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to return to a pure Ubuntu set-up, then the best way is to uninstall all of the Lubuntu applications.  Psycho cat's blog has a how to command for each version.  For versions 12.04 and before http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu
For versions after 12.04
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-ubuntu/
Since you did not mention your version number, merely go to the appropriate web site and paste the respective command in your terminal.  If you have things that you cannot live without, please back up because you never know what may happen.

Comment: I m using ubuntu 15.04. Will this command uninstall my gnome?

Comment: Only use the command for uninstalling Lubuntu/lxde.  That should not bother your Unity (Ubuntu) install.  However I would back up because you never know what will happen.